# Java error: illegal start of expression in my code

Tags: java

I'm getting the error: illegal start of expression and don't know how to fix this. This is all declarations for a program I need to write with guidelines. The program is meant to calculate the cost of a boat. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class boat
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  //declarations
....
double depreciationYear1 = bookValueBeginningYear1 * (2 * 100% / 3);
                                                        ^
double bookValueBeginningYear2 = bookValueBeginningYear1 - depreciationYear1;
double depreciationYear2 = bookValueBeginningYear2 * (2 * 100% / 3);
                                                        ^
double bookValueBeginningYear3 = bookValueBeginningYear2 - depreciationYear2;
double depreciationYear3 = bookValueBeginningYear3 * (2 * 100% / 3);
....                                                    ^
double exciseTaxYear1 = 90% * boatPrice/1000 * 25; 
                            ^
double exciseTaxYear2 = 80% * boatPrice/1000 * 25; 
                            ^
double exciseTaxYear3 = 70% * boatPrice/1000 * 25; 
....                        ^
double insuranceYear1 = boatPrice * 1% + bookValueBeginningYear1* 3%; 
                                                                    ^
double insuranceYear2 = boatPrice * 1% + bookValueBeginningYear2* 3%; 
                                                                    ^
double insuranceYear3 = boatPrice * 1% + bookValueBeginningYear3* 3%; 
....                                                                ^
```

Comment: What do you think `100% / 3` does? If you want to represent percentages, try using decimal values... 100% is  1, 90% is .90, and so forth.

Answer (score 5):

```
(2 * 100% / 3);
```

instead use:

```
(2 * 100 / 3);     // Just remove the % from all the statement.
```

Because you are using two operator (`%`, `/`) at once.

This is the error into all the statement in the code, which you have marked.

The `%` is a modulus operator in java, which is used for calculating remainders of two number like `10%4 is 2`. You might be getting confused by considering it as percentage.

Comment: This is of course the problem; why would it be downvoted?

Comment: @Pointy most likely somebody downvoting because the question is along the lines of a syntax error/why isn't my code working and should be closed/commented and not answered.

Comment: @Pointy I am also wondering, I hope, downvoter will provide the missing part here.

Comment: @SterlingArcher May I ask, what is wrong in answering the question. I know it is very trivial. People come with missing semi-colon and brackets.

Comment: It might be helpful to mention that the `%` operator has nothing to do with percentages, which the OP apparently thinks it does.

Comment: Going along with what @Griffey mentioned, it may also be helpful to provide a fix for OP's problem,

Comment: I never said anything was wrong, I just said that might have been the flight path for @downvoter is all.

Answer (score 1):

In Java

**%  Modulus operator**

Divides left hand operand by right hand operand and returns remainder

Example: B % A will give 0

**/ Division operator**

Divides left hand operand by right hand operand

Example: B / A will give 2

So in your case **2 * 100 % / 3** 
doesn't make any sense hence it is illegal

Have a quick look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm) to know the basic java operators